# Toggle active state on button in v-for loop using Vue 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm making a filter header in Vue 3 where you select one category to view at once, so you can click to toggle on and off that filter and also if you click another, it deselects the previous active one, only one or none ever active at once.

I've found examples such as this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gxz9y8q/) which 1. doesn't have a toggleable button (click again to deselect) and 2. doesn't use a v-for loop. I am fairly confident I can transfer it to a v-for loop, but I do not know how to go about the toggling + one active at a time aspect easily.

Here's my base code:

```html
<button
  v-for="category in contentCategories"
  @click=""
  class="filter-button"
>
  {{ category }}
</button>
```

```js
const contentCategories = ["category 1", "category 2", "category 3"];

let list = contentStore.resources;
const activeCategory = "";
const filteredList = list
  .filter((e) => e.category === activeCategory)
  .map((e) => {
    return e;
});
```

The behavior that I think I need is storing the active category in the `activeCategory` string, and applying the active tag to the corresponding button, and then be able to remove that `activeCategory` if the active button is clicked again OR change the `activeCategory` if a different button is clicked.

Apologies if this is an easy solution, I'm very new to Vue. Thank you!

Comment: Add currentCategory to the state (`ref` for composition api) and store category id (array index for static array) there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using composition API

Simple solution using additional ref for tracking

```
const selectedCategory = ref("")
const contentCategories = ref(["category 1", "category 2", "category 3"]);

<button
  v-for="category in contentCategories"
  @click="handleClick(category)"
  :class="selectedCategory === category ? 'active' : 'inactive'"
  :key="category"
>
  {{ category }}
</button>

handleClick(category) {
   selectedCategory.value = category
|
```

Tracking category activity if you want to have ability for multiple selections

```
const contentCategories = ref([
  {
    name: "Category 1",
    active: false
  },
  ...
]);

<button
  v-for="category in contentCategories"
  @click="handleClick(category)"
  :class="category.active ? 'active' : 'inactive'"
  :key="category"
>
  {{ category }}
</button>

handleClick(category) {
   find category and then set active = !active, turn off others
|
```

Comment: Would make sense for multiple selections at once but a burden for a single selection. Also contentCategories is not reactive

Comment: Yeah, thought he might use it for multi filtering but yep. Added simpler solution

Comment: Took that simpler solution and added a bit more for the toggle functionality and it worked great now, thanks! Does the button `v-for` loop need a `:key` binding or does it not matter?

Comment: Yes key indeed matters, its function is to track your reactive state changes which is contentCategories here. You need to use a unique value for it, here category name will suffice, otherwise it might render incorrectly.